# Bash- if clause doesn't work correctly

Tags: bash

I want to make a shutdown script and it doesn't work as intended. This is what I wrote.

```
echo "Wanna shutdown (y/n)?"

 read ANSWER

if [ $ANSWER=="y" ]
     then
        sudo shutdown -P now
else 
    printf "Something...."
```

whatever i press it just shuts down. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put spaces around the == operator. Otherwise the test expression is a single word, and all non-empty words test successfully.

In addition, if you wish to be portable, you should use `=` instead of `==`. And it is always wise to double quote variable expansions because `[` won't do that for you.

```
if [ "$ANSWER" = y ]; then
```

On the other hand, if you are using bash (or ksh or zsh) you could use the more forgiving `[[` conditional expression:

```
if [[ $ANSWER = y ]]; then
```

Comment: Indeed that was the mistake. Thank you! I need to wait 7 minutes before accepting this answer, so I will do so as soon as the time passes.